# dealloc or remove ViewControllers in self.navigationController after popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES is called

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am using a logout button that calls the

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

method. After this is called I want to dealloc or remove the previous ViewControllers stored in the 'stack' of `self.navigationController.viewControllers`

I have tried a couple of ways to delete the 'stack', one by:

```
NSMutableArray *stack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[stack removeAllObjects];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = stack;
```

so far nothing I've done deletes the stack. And I know they are not being deleted because I test it by

```
NSLog(@"%d", (int)self.navigationController.viewControllers.count);
[self.navigationController popToViewController:self.navigationController.viewControllers[2];
```

and it still pops to the ViewController.

any ideas?

---

Update: Logic in the calls

**ViewController that calls the Pop method**

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

**RootViewController**

```
NSLog(@"%d", (int)self.navigationController.viewControllers.count);
[self.navigationController popToViewController:self.navigationController.viewControllers[2];
```

Comment: Maybe not a problem with removing VCs from stack, but adding them to the navigation stack? Multiple instances of VC getting pushed or VCs getting retained in the code so they are not released when popped?

Comment: when you popviwecontroller that remove from navigation stack my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Your stack would have been removed as soon as you call popViewController: to check
try this

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:self.navigationController.viewControllers[2];
 double delayInSeconds = .1;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
NSLog(@"%d", (int)self.navigationController.viewControllers.count);
    });
```

instead of

```
NSLog(@"%d", (int)self.navigationController.viewControllers.count);
[self.navigationController popToViewController:self.navigationController.viewControllers[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should log view controllers in the stack **after** you call `popToViewController:` method (In the code you provided you have `NSLog` method **before** you call `popToViewController:` method.
Just try this code and see that "BEFORE POP" is larger than "AFTER POP".

```
NSLog(@"BEFORE POP: %d", (int)self.navigationController.viewControllers.count);
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
NSLog(@"AFTER POP: %d", (int)self.navigationController.viewControllers.count);
```

`popToViewController` method will remove all `viewController`s which were added to the stack after the `viewController` you pass as a parameter. And it does not matter if you pass `YES` in `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`, the stack will be updated right after you call this method before the animation is finished. Although the actual view controller object will probably be still retained until the animation is finished, but that's `UINavigationController`'s job, so do not worry about that.

Comment: i am. i call that in the VC that i am poping to

Comment: Accroding to the code you provided you are logging the count **before** you call `popToViewController: ` method

Comment: i am logging the number of VC in the stack after the popToRootViewController is called. Check update

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

will update the stack contents after the pop animation is complete.

So assuming you have a hierarchy like this:

NavigationController
   RootViewController
       FirstViewController
           SecondViewController

your stack count should be 3

if you call
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
within any of the view controllers, at the end of the animation, your hierarchy should look like this:

NavigationController
   RootViewController

and you stack count should be 1

If this isn't the case, then perhaps you are somehow corrupting the stack in code we haven't seen yet.

Comment: it will update the stack to only contain the root view controller

Comment: well when i call that it does not update the stack then because all of the previous VC are in the stack still

Comment: have you waited for the animation to complete before testing that assertion?

Comment: Or, try it without the animation: [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]. The stack should be updated immediately in this case

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49950/discussion-between-noah-passalacqua-and-tjboneman)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ARC? If so, the popped view controllers will be automatically deallocated. If they are not deallocated then there are some variables which are retained by ARC. Take a look at your code and see if you have some strong references declared inside the view controllers.

For example, properties which are not IBOutlets causes ARC to retain them even when the view controllers are popped out from the navigation controller, and dealloc is never called on these view controllers. Transform these properties into private variables and then use public methods to access them.

Comment: i changed all my properties to retain instead of weak. idk if thats what i was supposed to do. but it runs the same...

Comment: also deleted retain so it is just set to nonatomic.

Comment: well, in my experience I had the same problem, and the solution was to transform all the properties into private variables, as I said in the asnwer below. I don't think that changing the properties to retain will solve the problem...

Comment: no, if you specify nothing the default value is strong, which is bad :)

Comment: @albernala no i did not.. it still is not removing the items in the stack